# AVCaptureSession and Preview Layer does not fill entire screen

Tags: ios, swift3, avfoundation, avcapturesession

So, I'm trying to use the camera on my phone in my app, and I was successful, but unfortunately, when using the preview, the layer does not fill the entire screen [Here is an image to show you what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkx2W.jpg)

Here's my code:

```
if let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession) {
        self.previewLayer = previewLayer
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
        self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame
        captureSession.startRunning()

        let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        dataOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString):NSNumber(value:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]

        dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

        if captureSession.canAddOutput(dataOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
        }

        captureSession.commitConfiguration()


        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.Osmo.captureQueue")
        dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
    }
```

Comment: Try to set `self.view.layer.bounds` instead

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. Is there anything else I could do?

Comment: Where are you calling this piece of code?

Comment: In my ViewController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
if let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession) {
        self.previewLayer = previewLayer
        self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(self.previewLayer, at: 0)
        captureSession.startRunning()

        let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        dataOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString):NSNumber(value:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]

        dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

        if captureSession.canAddOutput(dataOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
        }

        captureSession.commitConfiguration()


        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.Osmo.captureQueue")
        dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

This may happen because you're trying to set a preview layer's frame from view which has auto layout constraints. Try to add an override of `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method to your view controller:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds
}
```

Comment: thank you @ninjaproper, above code solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try following piece of code :

```
 if let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession) {
                    previewLayer.bounds = view.bounds
                    previewLayer.position = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY)   //CGPointMake(view.bounds.midX, view.bounds.midY)
                    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                    let cameraPreview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height));
                    cameraPreview.tag = 44221007
                    cameraPreview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                    //cameraPreview.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector(("saveToCamera:"))))
                    view.addSubview(cameraPreview)
                    self.view.sendSubview(toBack: cameraPreview);

                }
```

Apple Doc : 
[image: AVFoundation class image]